# Joomla wrong path to media directory causes long loading

Tags: php, css, joomla

We have a problem with the following Joomla! 3.1 site: 
http://www.kurapotheke-igls.at/

There are two css files included by the :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

Here the path is wrong, there are two slashes in the front which shouldn't be there. I testet it with YSlow and this two files causes the extreme loading time of the site.

Strange is also, when I look at the website code this two files are included twice:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.kurapotheke-igls.at/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.kurapotheke-igls.at/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
```

Here is the code of the index.php file:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;
// Add current user information
$user = JFactory::getUser();
// Add Bootstrap Framework
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
// Add page class suffix
$itemid = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getItem($itemid);
$params = $menu->getParams( $active->id );
$pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"     lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/icons/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/css/k2style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/css/joomla.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />



<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/css/styles/<?php echo $this->params->get('templateStyles'); ?>.css" type="text/css" />
<?php if (isset($_GET['style'])) { $styles = $_GET['style']; }
if (isset($styles)) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/css/styles/style<?php 
    if ($styles == '1') {echo '1';} elseif ($styles == '2') {echo '2';} elseif ($styles == '3') {echo '3';} elseif ($styles == '4') {echo '4';} elseif ($styles == '5') {echo '5';} elseif ($styles == '6') {echo '6';} elseif ($styles == '7') {echo '7';} elseif ($styles == '8') {echo '8';} elseif ($styles == '9') {echo '9';} elseif ($styles == '10') {echo '10';} ?>.css" type="text/css" /> <?php } 
    else { echo ""; } ?>

<!-- Google Font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo ($this->params->get('googleFont')) ? $this->params->get('googleFont') : "Open+Sans"; ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo ($this->params->get('textLogoGoogleFont')) ? $this->params->get('textLogoGoogleFont') : "Open+Sans"; ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<?php // Parameters
require("admin/params.php"); ?>

<?php // Google Analytics Tracking Code
if($analyticsCode) {echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; echo $analyticsCode; echo '</script>';}?>

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/backtop/backtop.js"></script>

</head>
```

Do you have any idea why joomla includes this wrong files?

Comment: Why exactly are you including these files individually given that you are loading the framework?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, in my case a module published in the home page was trying to load the bootstrap.min.css, but the php file of that module was misspelled. The path was whit a slash before the media directory, generating the link to //media/jui... 
Try searching in your modules code for "/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" and remove the slash. It works for me.

```
JHTML::stylesheet('media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead which makes use of Joomla's `JHtml` method.

So replace this:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet('media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
```

with this:

```
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root() . 'media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
```

Comment: OK I changed it and found out that there is an error in your code :) ... you have to use JUri::root() --> double ::.
But this didnt helped. Now the two lines which included the right css files are missing and the website was 'destroyed'. 
Andy other idea?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, made a mistake there :/ Updated the code

Comment: I think it should be "stylesheet" rather than "script".

Comment: OK now your codes works ... but the long loading time is still not solved ... I found out that this two files are included twice - look at my question, i added something

Comment: Well these file are big. If you decide to use Bootstrap the one must suffer with long loading times. You can cache the CSS (solutions for this on Google) and also bare in mind that you are also importing multiple JS file such as jQuery, mootools and so on. As for the duplicate of the CSS file, did you **replace** you old code with the code I have provided? If so then try simply removing it totally as they might be imported from somewhere else

Comment: Try either removing your old code altogther or putting a space after #.  I never use hashtag commenting, but all examples I see have the space.  As for speed, two copies should be as fast as one as they load at the same time.  Using the hosted version on bootstrapcdn may be faster - http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ .

Comment: the bootstrap files are not really the problem. the problem seems that the system cant find the css files which are linke that way: //media/jui/css/... This lines are totally useless.
When I change the template the site loads fast. It seems that the templates generate this two lines somewhere

Comment: Have you deleted your old code?  In your updated code above you have just commented it out (and I'm unsure about the hashtag without a space method of doing this).  Try deleting the old code altogether.

Comment: OK I have removed that two lines ... but this did not help ... 
I often use # for comments, also without space - so I'm sure this works as comment ;)

Comment: In that case, I'd download all your files and do a search for "bootstrap.min.css" in them.  You must be calling that somewhere else via your original method.

Answer (score 0):

Addstylesheet has to contain the full URL path, unless it is linked to from the template.

So `$doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::base().'media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');` should work.

Ref: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

I believe *from a template* you can just use $this-> and a relative URL, ie `$this->addStyleSheet('media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css');`

Ref: http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet

Comment: Hi now i found the SOLUTION. 
With the following lines: 
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
it works!